Existence of analytic metrics on analytic manifolds
Let $X$ be a real analytic manifold, and let $E$ be a real analytic vector bundle. Does there always exist an analytic metric on $E$? By analytic metric I mean that if $U \subset X$ is an analytic chart, with analytic trivialisation $E|_U \cong \mathbb R^r \times U$, the coefficients of the metric are analytic.
Usually, the existence of metrics on vector bundles is proved by choosing local trivializations $E|_{U_i} \cong \mathbb R^r \times U_i$, and then gluing the standard metrics using a partition of unity, subordinate to $\{U_i\}$. However, partitions of unity are famously non-analytic, so the resulting metric is also not analytic.
Any reference would be appreciated.

Context: Existence of analytic metrics appears in Voisin's Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry, I, proof of Proposition 9.5. In that case, $\mathcal X$ is a complex manifold, $X_0 \subset \mathcal X$ is a compact complex submanifold, and one needs an analytic metric on $\mathcal X$ in a neighbourhood of $X_0$. The aim is to produce a tubular neighbourhood whose fibers are analytic submanifolds of $\mathcal X$.

To cut down on technicalities, let me assume that $M$ is compact (but the result holds in general).
Let $\pi: E\to M$ be a real-analytic fiber bundle  over a (real-analytic) manifold $M$. For instance, in your case you take $E$ to be the positive cone subbundle in the symmetric square $S^2T^*M$ of the cotangent bundle of $M$. I will equip $E$ with some $C^\infty$ background Riemannian metric in order to define convergence. Then every $C^\infty$-section $s\in \Gamma(M,E)$ is the $C^\infty$-limit of real-analytic sections. In particular, every $C^\infty$-Riemannian metric on $M$ is the limit of real-analytic metrics.
In order to prove this, observe that $E$ is a real-analytic manifold. Hence, the section $s$ is the $C^\infty$-limit of real-analytic maps $f_k: M\to E$ (you probably know how to prove this). Consider the compositions $h_k:= \pi\circ f_k$. The maps $h_k$, of course, need not be the identity map, but they $C^\infty$-converge to the identity map. Hence, for all sufficiently large $k$, each $h_k$ is a diffeomorphism $M\to M$. Now, replace $f_k$ with $s_k:=f_k\circ h^{-1}_k$. By the  construction, $\pi\circ s_k=id_M$, i.e. each $s_k$ is a section of $E\to M$. Clearly, $s_k$'s $C^\infty$-converge to $s$ and are real-analytic.
This argument also works for noncompact manifolds but then one has to use a more refined notion of approximation to get that approximants of a diffeomorphism are again diffeomorphisms, see for instance Munkres' book ("Elementary differential topology") for details.
